# Uploading to Swift Container with Metadata

Tags: java, openstack-swift, jclouds

im using Java and the jclouds SDK to upload files to a Swift container as multipart, the uploading is going fine yet i need to add metadata to the file, i noticed that there is a function  called `getContentMetadata()` which can get a metadata such as content length and type, yet i was unable to add custom metadata, tried to cast put options to metadata, didn't generate error but that generated an exception when i ran the code, the code is here

```
try {
        PutOptions putOptions = PutOptions.Builder.metadata(ImmutableMap.of("test", String.valueOf(strValue)));
        ByteSource fileBytes = Files.asByteSource(file);
        Payload payload = Payloads.newByteSourcePayload(fileBytes);
        ///setting the header for the request
        payload.getContentMetadata().setContentLength(file.length());
        payload.getContentMetadata().setContentType(contentType);
        payload.setContentMetadata((MutableContentMetadata) putOptions);

        Blob blob = blobStore.blobBuilder(file.getName()).payload(payload).build();
        ///sednig the request

        blobStore.putBlob("testContainer", blob, multipart());
        return contentLength;
    }
```

the line `payload.setContentMetadata((MutableContentMetadata) putOptions);` generated an exception

any idea how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set metadata via `BlobBuilder`, e.g.,

```
Blob blob = blobStore.blobBuilder(file.getName())
    .payload(fileBytes)
    .contentLength(file.length()
    .contentType(contentType)
    .userMetadata(ImmutableMap.of("test", String.valueOf(strValue)))
    .build();
```